# Is it possible to do screen recording without using foreground service for Android app targeting API 29?

Tags: android, android-mediaprojection

The following code works fine for devices lower than Android 10

```
startActivityForResult(mProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), REQUEST_CODE_SCREEN_RECORDING);
...
MediaProjectionCallback mMediaProjectionCallback = new MediaProjectionCallback();
mMediaProjection = mProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);
mMediaProjection.registerCallback(mMediaProjectionCallback, null);
startRecording();
```

Android 10 throws the following exception for ProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data):

```
Exception: Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2071)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1987)
    at android.media.projection.IMediaProjection$Stub$Proxy.start(IMediaProjection.java:231)
    at android.media.projection.MediaProjection.<init>(MediaProjection.java:75)
    at android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(MediaProjectionManager.java:104)
```

Yes, AndroidManifest.xml has the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

[The official document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjectionManager) says the following:

> Apps targeting SDK version Build.VERSION_CODES.Q or later should
> specify the foreground service type using the attribute
> R.attr.foregroundServiceType in the service element of the app's
> manifest file. The
> ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION attribute should
> be specified.

Could anyone offer a tip on this?

Comment: The exception seems very explicit on what is required.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Does it mean that I have no choice but to use a service?